# Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to ‘true’

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have a piece of code like this which will append the url depending on the bool value passes to the function (simplified code shown) below:

```
public static string function ( string url, bool val)
{
    if(val)
    {
       return url + "a";
    }
    else if(!val)
    {
       return url + "b";
    }
    else
        return url + "c";
 }
```

So in Else if part , I am getting a Sonarqube bug "Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to ‘true’ ; some subsequent code is never executed. Can someone help or guide me on this?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: It is quite unclear how you want to "change" the condition as the only thing shown in the question is `!val` and indeed on `else` branch of `if (val)` the value of `val` can only be false... Normally one would not even have any condition on such `else` branch but you for some reason need one. Please [edit] the question to explain why regular `if (cond) {...} else {...}` did not work for you.

Comment: I've edited code in the question to be [mre] - please review that guidance for future questions. Unfortunately it is still unclear how you expect checking a bool value to have 3 distinct variants.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to handle 3 cases. Either append "sometext", append "someOtherText", or return the url unchanged. val can only handle 2 of these cases since it can only be or true or false (unlike javascript where it can also be undefined). Maybe change it to a nullable type? There's probably a better way to do it though.

```
private static string function(string url, bool? val)
    {
        if (val == true)
        {
            return url + "a";
        }
        else if (val == false)
        {
            return url + "b";
        }
        else
            return url + "c";
    }
```

Comment: This is an adjustment in the wrong direction. Changing the parameter to be nullable may eliminate the message, but the message is due to the fact that the code is logically wrong--that's what it's designed to indicate. So now you have two things that are wrong. OP needs to learn that `if (val) {...} else if (!val) {...} else {...}` is wrong for a non-nullable `bool` and `if (val) {...} else {...}` is sufficient, not learn to unnecessarily make it nullable.